# Syncing multiple Google Sheets worksheets into one large Google Sheet document

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I have several different Google Sheets workbooks with multiple pages that I'm trying to have sync into a master file whenever they are edited. I cannot have all of the people on the separate documents editing the primary document. In using the Script Editor, I have this:

```
   function onEdit() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Admin Settings")
     .addItem("Import Data", "importData")
   }
  
    var sourceSpreadsheetID = "TO UPDATE";
    var sourceWorksheetName = "TO UPDATE";
    var targetSpreadsheetID = "TO UPDATE";
    var targetWorksheetName = "TO UPDATE";

   function importData() {
    var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1yoF-IQo_XKD1X6N_z_54X8N4Akm4dgyUTJ9Av6wQ0Ps');
    var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Barnhardt");
    var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
    var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ktwfwRN3cRCvpwkiFbZMEud-9ez8ZVGciu5ejrNiGAU');
    var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Barnhardt");
    var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns()) toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues()); 
   }
```

but I can't figure out why it won't work. The script editor says that it was successful. I also tried to add a trigger so that every time the document is edited, it will update the master document, but I'm not sure how to add that to the script. Help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. First things first. Change `onEdit()` to `onOpen()": assuming that you want the menu at all, you'll want to create it when you open the spreadsheet not when you edit a field.

Answer (score 1):

Your `onEdit` trigger doesn't actually execute the function, it merely creates a menu option. So, first things first, assuming that you want the menu at all, change `onEdit()` to `onOpen()`. This will create the menu so that you can execute it manually whenever you want.

Second, manually create an `onEdit()` trigger for `importData()`. This will execute the function whenever there is a change in the data. You could create the trigger programmatically, but this probably isn't the time or the place to explain that in detail.

FYI, if you have a function called `onEdit`, then the trigger will be automatically recognised by virtue of using that function name. Same applies for `onOpen()`. What you do NOT want is to end up with two functions called `onEdit()` - that's a recipe for a problem.

Lastly, if the script is bound to "thisspreadsheet", then you don't need to open it by ID, you could just use `var thisSpreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.